# How to filter json via jsonschema in python

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I have a json file in Python and a relative json-schema, 
I want to filter out form the input json file all the element that do not satify the relative json-schema.

For example:


*Schema*

```
{
  "type":"object",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
  "required":false,
  "properties":{
    "address": {
      "type":"object",
      "required":true,
      "properties":{
        "city": {
          "type":"string",
          "required":true
        },
        "houseNumber": {
          "type":"number",
          "required":false
        },
        "streetAddress": {
          "type":"string",
          "required":true
        }
      }
    },
    "phoneNumber": {
      "type":"array",
      "required":false,
      "items":
      {
        "type":"object",
        "required":false,
        "properties":{
          "number": {
            "type":"string",
            "required":false
          },
          "type": {
            "type":"string",
            "required":false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Json input:*

```
{
  "address":{
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city":"New York",
    "houseNumber":12
  },
  "phoneNumber":
    [
    {
      "type":"home",
      "number":"212 555-1234",
      "description":"blabla"
    }
  ]
}
```

The element **"description":"blabla"** is not present in the json schema and has to be filtered.

*Json output:*

```
{
  "address":{
    "streetAddress": "21 2nd Street",
    "city":"New York",
    "houseNumber":12
  },
  "phoneNumber":
    [
    {
      "type":"home",
      "number":"212 555-1234"
    }
  ]
}
```

I found this https://github.com/alank64/json-schema-filter but it is for javascript. 
Are you aware of any script able to do it in python?

Comment: JSON Schema is designed for validation and not filtering data.

Comment: Could you share the solution if you have solved the issue? Thanks!

Comment: I would assume that you need a json schema validator in order to do this filtering. So I think you could ask in https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema to see if there is any way to use that package to easily implement the filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution: http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/normalization-rules.html#purging-unknown-fields